# How to remove this setting in Vs Code Text Editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I don't know where in the settings are the option to remove the `"index:"` inside the red box in the image. the image with the red box
[image: the image with the red box]

I looked through all the Text Editor settings in Vs Code but didn't find any option that solve the problem. I expect that someone know where is this option.

Comment: search the settings for `hints`

Answer (score 1):

"inlay hints" has been enabled by default you can go to setting then type "inlay hints".

you can enable or disable it